# Is any way to create different root categories for different store

Tags: magento2, store-view

I have two store one is English and  another is France.I have multiple category in English store.But I want to create these all category in France Language for France store.
Manually this is possible for me to change store and change the category name English to  France. This is working perfect. Can I create different root category for a different store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right you want a new root category, then please follow this:

**To create a new root category**

**Step 1: Build a New Root Category**

On the Admin Panel, *Product > Inventory > Categories*.

Click on Add Root Category button. Then choose Yes in the Is Active field to activate the root. Make the new root category visible if choosing Yes in the Include in Navigation Menu field.

After finishing General Information, move to Display Settings tab and choose Yes for the Is Anchor.
Click Save Category to use the new root category.

**Step 2: Create Subcategories for the New Root Category**

Look at the left of the setting page, choose the new root category you created appears there to start this step.
Click on Add Subcategory.
Name for the subcategory in the Name field.
Choose Yes in the Is Active field.
Click Save Category to complete.
Do all again if you need to create other new subcategory.

**Step 3: Activate the New Root Category on Your Store**

On the Admin Panel, *Stores > Settings > All Stores*.
Under Stores, hit the Main Website Store link.
In the Root Category, choose the new root category.
Click on Save Store on the top right corner to apply the category.

For each store view you can set the root category differently.

Comment: Well when you have two store for main website then how can you chose  different root category for  different store, when i select different root category  for french then  English is also override the same category

Comment: You want the 2 stores to have different categories/catalogs? Then you need a 2nd website

Comment: but when i create second website then , my store swticher is disable

Comment: If you have 2 stores under 1 website then the root category will be the same. You can find more here https://www.sherodesigns.com/magento-tutorial-creating-multiple-store-views-in-magento/